# Sqlite function for addition to a member in database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Lets assume this. 
I have a database name 'school' 
table named 'class' 
2 columns : 'name'  and 'marks'

suppose an entry or row :  'name' :'John'   and   'score' :'50'.

Now I am trying to add another 50 to the score of this instance so that it becomes 100 but I don't want to query the present value of score from database and then add 50 and update it again.  That would be quite lame.

But instead I want to add 50 directly to the score without querying it.

Comment: Do you want to modify the value in the score column or just show the current value with an additional 50?

Comment: I want to modify score's value in the database itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can self reference a column in an update statement:

```
UPDATE class
SET    score = score + 50
WHERE  name = 'John'
```